# Facebook insights data retrieval

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to pull data from the Facebook API and I am testing it on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer but I keep getting error code 200 in my R code, instead of meaningful data.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

```
{
    "data": [],
    "paging": {
        "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/733853743/insights/page_impressions?access_token=access_token&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&since=1451200046&suppress_http_code=1&until=1451459246",
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/733853743/insights/page_impressions?access_token=access_token&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&since=1451718446&suppress_http_code=1&until=1451977646"
    }
}
```

Comment: formatting and title

Answer (score 0):

200 is not an error code, and the result looks like it worked. There is just no data. I assume you forgot to authorize with the `read_insights` permission in the API explorer. You may just get an empty array then.

Btw, you are trying to get insights of a User Profile. You can only get insights for Pages.

Comment: I tried this and I still get the same result. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Could it be the access token?

Comment: i just realized that you are trying to get insights from a user profile, see my answer. there are no insights for profiles.

Comment: Oh...So are there only insights for "Pages" like fan pages and stuff?

Comment: of course. user profiles don´t have insights. you are not allowed to use them for commercial reasons anyway.